# CSS transform applied to SVG during animation persists on Safari, not Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, svg, safari, css-animations

Upon hovering over an inline `svg` element, I'm animating a `polygon` element using CSS animations and the `transform` property.

Desired behavior: If a user hovers and then stops hovering mid-animation, I want the animated element to return to its original state.

On Chrome and Firefox, this works as expected. On Safari, the transforms applied during the animation persist.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/tillytoby/pen/dyPzmvM

Code:

HTML

```
<svg width="200" height="250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
  <rect x="60" y="10" rx="10" ry="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <circle cx="25" cy="75" r="20" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
  <ellipse cx="75" cy="75" rx="20" ry="5" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <line x1="10" x2="50" y1="110" y2="150" stroke="orange" stroke-width="5"/>
  <polyline points="60 110 65 120 70 115 75 130 80 125 85 140 90 135 95 150 100 145"
      stroke="orange" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <polygon points="50 160 55 180 70 180 60 190 65 205 50 195 35 205 40 190 30 180 45 180"
      stroke="green" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <path d="M20,230 Q40,205 50,230 T90,230" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg polygon {
  transform: none;
}

svg:hover polygon {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 47px 192px;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

I've tried applying `transform: none;` to the `polygon` when the `svg` isn't being hovered, and also applying `animation-fill-mode: none;`, neither of which seemed to have any effect.

Any idea for the discrepancy on Safari? Thanks for any help!